# Equivalence of regular grammars

Tags: computability, regular-languages, formal-grammars, decision-problem

I know that proving context free grammars equivalent is undecidable. I also know that proving if a context free grammar recognizes a regular language is undecidable. Here is my question: is proving that two regular grammars recognize the same language decidable?

Comment: Do you know if regular grammars are deterministic? I know equivalence is decidable for DCFL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_pushdown_automaton#Equivalence_problem

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: A minor quibble. One usually says that a grammar *generates* a language and a machine (like a finite automaton) *recognizes* a language.

Comment: @ Raphael does Equality" and "Equivalence" are two different things for any type of grammar?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is decidable. There's a rather direct conversion from a regular grammar to an NFA. From there, run the subset construction to turn the NFAs into DFAs. Run minimization algorithms to convert each DFA to a canonical minimum DFA, then decide whether the two DFAs are equivalent. Each transformation preserves the language represented, so this ultimately decides whether the two grammars have the same language.